# R function converting text file into document term matrix

Tags: r, text-mining

I have text file with three columns which are document id, term id and term frequency. Is there an R function that converts this data to document term matrix?

Comment: Please read [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610) - questions should provide input data (e.g. add the result of `dput(mydata)`), the expected output, what lines of code you tried and in what way they failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text='"doc" "term" "freq"
1 "foo" 1
1 "bar" 2
2 "hello" 1
2 "world" 2')
library(tm)
dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(xtabs(freq~doc+term, df), weighting=weightTf)
as.matrix(dtm)
#     Terms
# Docs bar foo hello world
#    1   2   1     0     0
#    2   0   0     1     2
```